# Unable to install lib32gcc1

Tags: software-installation, libraries

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64 bit
So Whenever i try to do:

```
sudo apt install lib32gcc1
```

I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package lib32gcc1
```

I have tried everything, every tutorial.
A few things to mention:

1. It's for Steamcmd to run a server ( most likely won't because of 2 )
2. It's on a phone being emulated
   Now i think a port of it not working is because of it being on a phone.

Answer (score 1):

[lib32gcc1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lib32gcc1) exists in Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) repositories but only for the `amd64` hardware architecture.

This package is therefore not available for ARM, the typical hardware architecture of any modern smartphone where you could have installed some Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the info !